# How to Get a Last child from xml sheet in ruby using nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i need to get the last child for xml sheet in order to add another node every time to last child , i want to open an xml file and add another node to last one

```
xml  = File.open(DOCUMENT, 'r+')
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see an example of the XML you are using so I can provide you with the code but if you call xml.xpath("//+node+").children.last you will be provided with the last child in your XML.

Comment: this is a sample of the xml file im using , i want to always add a node for last child of Test Suite node:                        <?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Report.xsl"?>
<Report >
  <TestSuite Desc="Login"> <TestCase > <StepDetails>TestCase One</StepDetails><StepDetails >TestCase two</StepDetails></Step></TestCase></TestSuite>
</Report>

Answer (score 0):

```
file =  Nokogiri::XML(XML_FILE_PATH);
node =  Nokogiri::XML::Node.new(NODE_ELEMENT, file);

node.last();
```

Nokogiri last() documentation: http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html#method-i-last